# Is there a quicker way (< 16mins) to compile mongodb source code after modifying the kernel code?

Tags: mongodb

This is my first attempt at working on mongodb patches.

**After kernel code modification "time scons --mute=MUTE --dd mongod" with cacheDir() enabled takes ~16 mins on Ubuntu. Is there a way to compile mongod and 'all' quicker after modifying the kernal code (in my_repo/src/mongo/)?**

**Details:**

It is currently very time consuming to implement fixes to kernel code for mongodb jira patches when each compilation takes this long. An initial compilation of just the source directory containing the modified .h and .cpp files is done which is fairly quick but I need to eventually compile mongod and 'all' to run some minor tests as I incrementally develop. I went through the mongodb docs. and other sources too. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried contacting 10gen and asking your question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some general tips:

- Build a [more specific target](http://www.mongodb.org/about/contributors/scons/) than `all`.  If you are only changing mongod, for example, then: `scons mongod`.
- If you have multiple processors in your system, run scons with -j numprocs, eg: `scons -j4` for a quad core system.  This will run more jobs in parallel (the default is 1).
- Use `--d` (debug build); this builds with optimizations off.
- Don't use `--dd` (debug build with _DEBUG and extra asserts) unless you really need this and understand the additional overhead.
- If you have multiple computers available, you could also set up [`distcc`](https://code.google.com/p/distcc/) for distributed builds across multiple machines.

So putting the above options together, a better command line (assuming 4 cores available) should be: `scons -j4 --d mongod`.

You haven't mentioned hardware specs, but SSDs also make things Go Faster.

Just did some a quick check of timing on a Macbook Air (2.0ghz core i7, post-June 2012 model) with the above options.  Full build was 8 minutes 15s; incremental build after making small change to cpp file in src/mongo/db/ took ~30s.

Comment: Thinkpad 430 hardware specs:

- 2 cores, 4 processors.
- 2.5GHz Intel Core i5 3210M Processor
- I currently don't have an SSD.

The incremental builds from within emacs as usual take ~25 seconds.

The -j numprocs and --d helped. 

The targeted build, being mongod, used to take ~16 mins. It now takes ~6 mins with the above. Thanks!